# PowerShell greater than also includes item that is equal

Tags: powershell

I am writing a PowerShell script to sort the directory and return folders with the names that start with the number sequence that is greater than specified sequence, but -gt operator acts as a -ge operator.

Here is the code I'm running:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Users\USER\Testing -recurse | 
    Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -ge $true -and $_.Name -gt "003" -and $_.Name -match '^\d+.*$' } | 
        Select-Object Name
```

The response I get is:
005-folder
003-folder
004-folder

There seems to be the similar but opposite pattern for -le and -lt operators. Both of them do NOT include the equal item. So when I run

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Users\USER\Testing -recurse | 
    Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -ge $true -and $_.Name -le "003" -and $_.Name -match '^\d+.*$' } | 
        Select-Object Name
```

The response I get is:
001-folder
002-folder

I can't seem to find anything on the internet that solves the issue I am having, so I assume something in my scripts breaks the -gt and -le operators?

Comment: For starters you are missing underscores.  The variable the represents the current item in the Where-Object -FilterScript block is `$_`.  `$_.PSIsContainer -eq $true` (why using -ge?), Instead of using .PSIsContainer you can omit that and change your Get-ChildItem call to only return directories `Get-ChildItem \\path -Recurse -Directory`

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I switched my code to Directory. Looks cleaner. Underscore is erased by StackOverflow for some reason. If I go to edit my post - it's in place.

Comment: this >>> `$_.Name -gt "003"` <<< is comparing two strings. you are more likely to get an accurate comparison if you convert the `.BaseName` prefix to an `[int]` and compare to the integer  `3`, not the string `003`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured out the issue few minutes after I posted it. '003-folder' will be greater than '003' cause I'm comparing strings. Need to truncate first.

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Users\USER\Testing -recurse -Directory | 
Where-Object {$_.Name.subString(0, 3) -gt '003' -and $_.Name -match '^\d+.*$' } | 
Select-Object Name
```